# What array to use to store an Object?

Tags: java

I never stored an object of Strings in a java array before. So I do not know how to do it. Are there more than 1 ways to store an object into an array?

Comment: See [The Java Tutorials - Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)

Comment: If you don't **have to** use arrays, you can use lists instead which are easier to use.

Comment: no. into an array there is only a way. String[] obj = new String[size]; obj[0] = "your string"; There are lot of collections in which you can store your strings

Comment: Hmm... Maybe I asked this question wrongly. I created an `Object Class` which contains 4 String variables. And If I assigned these Strings with their respective values. Can I store them all in the **first index of an array**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, you have something like this

```
public class MyClass {
  public String one;
  public String two;
  public String three;
  public String four;

  public MyClass(String one, String two, String three, String four) {
    this.one = one;
    this.two = two;
    this.three = three;
    this.four = four;
  }
}
```

the you can store an instance of that class in an array:

```
MyClass[] myClasses = {new MyClass("one", "two", "three", "four")};
System.out.println(myClasses[0].one);  // will print "one"
```

---

There are some different ways to create an array (of Strings) and to set values:

**1.**

```
String[] strings = new String[3];
strings[0] = "one";
strings[1] = "two";
strings[2] = "three";
```

**2.**

```
String[] strings = new String[]{"one", "two", "three"};
```

**3.**

```
String[] strings = {"one", "two", "three"};
```

Comment: I learned this a while ago, I don't think it could solve what I want or intended. I am looking at an object class with Strings variables. Stored into an array.

Comment: The `Object` class has no fields to store Strings. It's pretty unclear what you want to achieve. What is your definition of an *object class*? Do you want an array of Strings as a field or an array of this *object class*?

Answer (score 2):

This line of steps maybe helpful to you..

In case of Array you can store only one kind of data,

```
Object[] myObjectArray = Object[NumberOfObjects];
myObjectArray[0] = new Object();
```

If you are talking about the String object, then you can store your String object also.

```
String[] myStringArray = String[NumberOfObjects];
myStringArray[0] = new String();

or

String[] myStringArray = String[NumberOfObjects];
myStringArray[0] = "Your String";
```

Here you can store your string object of Sting without using new operator.

Comment: This may look like the answer for me. Tell me, will this work if I created an `Object Class` with 4 String variables, each with its own values. Store it within **an index of an array**?

Answer (score 1):

Better way to use List, it is a collection interface. we are not storing objects , we are storing references(Memory addresses) of the objects. and use generics concept give more performance.

```
   Ex:

List<String> references = new ArrayList<String>(); 
List<OurOwnClass> references = new ArrayList<OurOwnClass>();
```

Comment: ArrayList? That is something new compared with the other answers. How easy is it to pick up ArrayList? After reading arrays in Java, it is quite easy to catch on. Any good tutorials I can reference?

Answer (score 0):

```
Object[] myObjectArray=new Object[numberOfObjects];
myObjectArray[0]=objectToStore;
```

and so on

Comment: Convention is to have variables start with small cap.

Comment: and you forget the new keyword

Comment: I also thought so after seeing the answers above.